# How to get the clientID, clientSecret, subscriptionId, tenantId of an app service in Azure with PowerShell or CLI

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I'm trying to get these properties from an Azure app service but cannot find the command in PowerShell or Azure CLI.  What is the command(s) to get these, if any?

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking, why an app service will have the clientID and clientSecret? Could you include more details? I suppose you enabled the Azure AD auth in `Authentication / Authorization`? And you want to get the information of the correspond AD App?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is registered as active directory app then you can use below PowerShell command

```
Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq 'TestName'"
```

Comment: I don't see Get-AzureADApplication.  I used Get-AzADApplication.  The error I got was the following:     Get-AzADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq 'test-app'"
Get-AzADApplication : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Filter'.
At line:1 char:21

Comment: use 
Get-AzADApplication -DisplayName "test-app"

Comment: That seems to work, however, I have access to two directories.  This is not pointing to the correct directory.  How would I change that?